# If...else within a for loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, matrix

I am writing a function to perform bit inversion for each row of a binary matrix which depends on a predefined `n` value. The `n` value will determine the number of `1` bits for each row of the matrix.

```
set.seed(123)
## generate a random 5 by 10 binary matrix
init <- t(replicate(5, {i <- sample(3:6, 1); sample(c(rep(1, i), rep(0, 10 - i)))}))
n <- 3
## init_1 is a used to explain my problem (single row matrix)
init_1 <- t(replicate(1, {i <- sample(3:6, 1); sample(c(rep(1, i), rep(0, 10 - i)))}))
```

The `bit_inversion` function does this few things:

1. If the selected row has number of `1's` lesser than `n`, then it randomly select a few indices (`difference`) and invert them. (`0` to `1`)
2. Else if the selected row has number of `1's` greater than `n`, then it randomly select a few indices (`difference`) and invert them. (`1` to `0`)
3. Else do nothing (when the row has number of `1's` equals to `n`.)

Below is the function I implemented:

```
bit_inversion<- function(pop){

        for(i in 1:nrow(pop)){ 
                difference <- abs(sum(pop[i,]) - n)
                ## checking condition where there are more bits being turned on than n
                if(sum(pop[i,]) > n){
                        ## determine position of 1's
                        bit_position_1 <- sample(which(pop[i,]==1), difference)
                        ## bit inversion
                        for(j in 1:length(bit_position_1)){
                                pop[bit_position_1[j]] <- abs(pop[i,][bit_position_1[j]] - 1)

                        } 
                } 

                else if (sum(pop[i,]) < n){
                        ## determine position of 0's
                        bit_position_0 <- sample(which(pop[i,]==0), difference)
                        ## bit inversion
                        for(j in 1:length(bit_position_0)){
                                pop[bit_position_0[j]] <- abs(pop[bit_position_0[j]] - 1)

                        }
                }
        }

        return(pop)
}
```

Outcome:

```
call <- bit_inversion(init)
> rowSums(call)  ## suppose to be all 3
 [1] 3 4 5 4 3
```

But when using `init_1` (a single row matrix), the function seems to work fine.

Outcome:

```
call_1 <- bit_inversion(init_1)
> rowSums(call)
[1] 3
```

Is there a mistake in my `for` and `if...else` loop?

Comment: That is hideous code for generating a 0/1 matrix. Try this: `nr <- 5; nc <- 10; init <- matrix(rbinom(nr*nc, 1, 0.5), nrow=nr, ncol=nc)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line in 'j' for loop

```
pop[bit_position_1[j]] <- abs(pop[i,][bit_position_1[j]] - 1)
```

into

```
pop[i,bit_position_1[j]] <- abs(pop[i,][bit_position_1[j]] - 1)
```

You forgot the row index.

And, here is a more compact version of your for loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(pop)){
  difference <- abs(sum(pop[i,]) - n)
  logi <- sum(pop[i,]) > n
  pop[i,sample(which(pop[i,]==logi), difference)] <- !logi
}
```